# How to sort the Resources files into one folder in VS2010？

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Environment: Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone

I have lots of resources files(*.resx) . i use  them to translate my app.I create a new folder named "Localized", I put all the resx file into the new folder, but it doesn't work.

How can I sort them into one folder?

Comment: _"but it doesn't work"_ What doesn't?

Comment: it means the project will not find the resources which i defined in the resx files -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what "doesn't work", this is a bit of a guessing game. My suspicion is the resource file names may not be following the correct naming conventions where:

> Each resource file must contain the correct culture/language name, as
>   described in [Culture and Language Support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).
>
> For example:
>
> - For the culture Spanish (Spain), use AppResources.es-ES.resx.
> - For the culture German (Germany), use AppResources.de-DE.resx.

**Other Resources**

- [How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [Localizing a Windows Phone app Step by Step](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Localizing-a-Windows-Phone-app-Step-by-Step)
- [Localization and Globalization in WP7 Applications Using Resource Files](http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/09/localization-and-globalization-in-wp7.html)

Comment: "it doesn't work" means an error like this "The type or namespace name 'AppResources' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) e:\User\Albert Gao\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\abcV1\abcV1\LocalizedResources.cs 16 24 abcV1
"

Comment: The error indicates there is a missing reference; check to make sure the localization files (resx) are set as an embedded resource (right click file, properties).